# Use Regex to get text after /

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this text from a website

```
<a class='link--wrapper' href='/china/sights/architecture/old-buildings'>
<a class='link--wrapper' href='/china/sights/nature-wildlife/giant-panda-breeding-research-base'>
```

but I'm having trouble only capturing the text after the / using re.findall
the best I can do so far is

```
Link = re.findall("(?<=sights/).*(?='>)", Webpage)
```

which returns

```
architecture/old-buildings
nature-wildlife/giant-panda-breeding-research-base
```

What i want returned is

```
old-buildings
giant-panda-breeding-research-base
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex includes the slash.  Use this:

```
/sights/.+/([^/']+)'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"(?<=sights\/.+\/).+(?='>)"
```